# Counting a sequence

Tags: r, count

I am looking to count the number of times the value is below a point and when it exceeds the threshold to start counting from start.

For example if I have
`X <- c(1,2,11,14,5,6,7,12)` and I am counting the number of times the values are less than 10 consecutively then I want an answer as

Output = 2,3
Since 1,2 are less than 10 so total 2 and then the count starts again for 5,6,7 and the total is 3

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`rle`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/rle) function :

```
with(rle(X < 10),lengths[values])
> [1] 2 3
```

**Brief explanation :**

1) `X < 10` returns : `c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)` so we just need to count batches of consecutive TRUE's

2) `rle(X < 10)` does exactly that, returning an object (a list with `lengths` and `values` properties) indicating the consecutive batches of values and their length. In this case :

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 2 2 3 1
  values : logi [1:4] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

3) So doing `RLE <- rle(X < 10); RLE$lengths[RLE$values]` we got exactly what you want, but creating a useless temporary variable `RLE` (not a big deal, actually), but using [`with`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/with) we just skip that passage.